# Get Param value passed after sucess of Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<a class="removeApp" data-app="12">Close Something </a>
$('.removeApp').click(function (e) {
   $.ajax({
       async: false,
       type: 'POST',
       url: '@Url.Action("Remove", "Something")',
       data: {
           id: $(this).data("app")
       },
       success: function (result, data) {
           console.log(this.data );  //gives id=12
           console.log (this.data["id"] ) ///gives nothing how do i get just 12
       }
    }) 
});
```

I am trying to get the data that is passed by parameter name how can i do so?

Comment: Where does your data come from? Are you just getting a `String` that is "id=12"? In which case you need to parse the string.

Comment: from the ancor data -app element

Comment: Can you post the server method you are POSTing to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the data should look something like "{'id' : 12}", this would then be JSON and you could use the `jQuery.getJSON()` function and this would return a javascript object - which is what you want.
I think that currently you're getting a string equal to "id=12" as a response - all HTTP data is a string, that's just how it works.
You can parse the string with a bit of javascript:

```
var id = parseInt(data.split("=")[1]);
```

That's a bit hardcoded and ugly however.

Comment: how do i get it if its {"id":9}
i tired this.data.id for above it returns undefined

Comment: Did you use the other jQuery function? Javascript needs to `eval` the JSON string.